# C++ equivalent of Java's paintcomponent?

Tags: java, c++, draw, paint, paintcomponent

After a good year on java, I've come to use the paint component so I can "visually" see my programs work.

I want to learn c++, but I simply cant visualize my programs by the console. Is there any recommendations for a library or header that is similar to javas paintcomponent?

I do not really mind buttons, textfields, I want to at least have a window open where my code paints on it. And please no win32, mfc or qt. I fear these are too complex for me for now, unless you really recommend it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are all kinds of frameworks. This isn't an appropriate question for SO, though. See the [faq].

Comment: Use [Qt frameworks](http://qt-project.org/)

Comment: If you are just starting to learn C++ don't make it more difficult by having to learn a large framework along with it.

Comment: If you have programmed in Java then QT is not that hard... The API is very similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And please no win32, mfc or qt. I fear these are too complex for me for now, unless you really recommend it.

Doing graphics without some kind of framework is actually *a lot harder* than using any one of the frameworks that you have listed.  Orders of magnitude harder ... if you could measure hardness objectively.

To echo other people's recommendations: [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) should be just fine.

---

> I want to learn c++, but I simply cant visualize my programs by the console.

I don't know if you are expressing yourself clearly, but if you really want to visualize your code (i.e. get some kind of pictorial representation *of the code structure*) then you should be looking for an IDE that understands C++.  Writing your own software to visualize your C++ code is like inventing a new kind hammer when you just need to hammer in a nail.